# Can Laravel route model binding work with nesting for middlewares?

Tags: laravel, authentication, authorization, middleware

I'm running this code to use my project policy for middlewares. It works as long as `{project}` is "last in the chain". Is there any way to make it work for deeper levels too?

```php
Route::middleware(['web', 'auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    //...

    Route::prefix('project/{project}')->middleware('can:view,project')->group(function () { // This works, but not if I go one more level after this...
        Route::get('/', function (Project $project) {
            return view('projects::show', [
                'project' => $project,
            ]);
        })->name('project');

        Route::prefix('settings')->middleware('can:update,project')->group(function () {
            // I get 403 here and I don't think I even get through the first middleware...
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either this

```
use App\Model\Project;

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'project/{project::id}',
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (Project $project) {
        return view('projects.show', [
                'project' => $project,
            ]);
    });

    Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'settings',
    ], function (Project $project) {  // this is the one line I am not sure of
        // some routes
    })->can('update', Project::class);

})->can('view', Project::class);
```

or

```
use App\Model\Project;

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'project/{project::id}',
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (Project $project) {
        return view('projects.show', [
                'project' => $project,
            ]);
    });

    Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'settings',
    ], function () use ($project) {  // this is the one line I am not sure of
        Route::get('/', function (Setting $setting) use ($project) {
            return view('project.settings.show', [
                    'project' => $project,
                    'settings' => $settings
                ]);
        });
    })->can('update', Project::class);

})->can('view', Project::class);
```

Way I think it should be done

```
use App\Model\Project;

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'project/{project::id}',
], function () {

    Route::middleware(['can:update, project'])->group(function () {

        Route::get('settings', function() {
             // do something
        })
    });

})->can('view', Project::class);
```

Comment: Sorry, just realized that `::` is in the question too; cheers for fixing it on your answer anyway 

Comment: Thanks, I get `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' `. I use modules in my app so `projects::show` is correct.

Comment: I don't know what your models look like so I will need to see them

Comment: This is the query it generates `select
  *
from
  projects
where
  `` = 442354557103870
  and projects.deleted_at is null
order by
  title asc
limit
  1`

Comment: What is your primary key?

Comment: Ahh, changing `project::id` to `project:id` fixed it. Still can't reach my second group however.

Comment: And how do you get `can:view,project` for the first group and `can:update,project` for the second group?

Comment: Oh sorry misread so you can get your project model, but you have another issue.

Comment: So I think we need to pass an array. However, can you user view and update because laravel will merge nested middleware. Also do you have a project middle?

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer I think that is correct now. I think you still need to pass the $project into the route group for the update middleware. Either that or a use a `use($project)` to pass it up the line

Comment: I get this with the new code `Call to a member function can() on null`. This is with only the last `->can('view', Project::class);` in place. Also just passing in the Project class wont work, since I need that particular model, no?

Comment: you need to add the use statement to your route file like in the answer

Comment: There's no `$project` to access there. Red squiggly line under it in the editor too. I may just do the authorization in the controllers. Thank you!

Comment: I mean why do you even need to do this with prefixes? You could just wrap those routes with middleware and not make another group. Ya without seeing any more code I think you are taking the wrong approach.

Comment: Ya the last block should work if you are just trying to get to a settings route with a project and have more middleware.